# вывести рандомный масссив через в реакте

Tags: reactjs

Дано: массив, из которого по нажатию кнопки нужно показать рандомное слово. Я понимаю, что нужно использовать `useState` и нет никаких проблем сделать это для стринга или числа, но никаких не отрендить для массива:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./RandomBrand.css";

function RandomBrand(): JSX.Element {


const [arrShoes, setShoes] = useState(["Adidas", "Nike", "Brandon Shoes", "Reebok", "Fila"])
const shoes = arrShoes[Math.floor(Math.random()*arrShoes.length)];

function getRandomBrand (): void {

    setShoes(shoes)
}

    return (
        <div className="RandomBrand">

         <button onClick={getRandomBrand}>Show me!</button>
         <span>Random shoe is: {shoes}</span>
            
        </div>
    );
}

export default RandomBrand;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все тоже самое надо делать, только в переменную сохранять элемент массива.

```
function RandomBrand(): JSX.Element {
  const [arrShoes, setShoes] = useState(["Adidas", "Nike", "Brandon Shoes", "Reebok", "Fila"]);
  const [shoes, selectShoes] = useState('Не выбрано');

  function getRandomBrand (): void {
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * arrShoes.length);
    selectShoes(arrShoes[random]);
  }

  return (
    <div className="RandomBrand">

      <button onClick={getRandomBrand}>Show me!</button>
      <span>Random shoe is: {shoes}</span>

    </div>
  );
}
```

**Что у вас происходило:**

Когда компонент рендерился, переменная `arrShoes` становилась массивом.
На следующей строке вы присваивали переменной `shoes` один из элементов массива `arrShoes`.

При нажатии на кнопку, вы переписывали переменную `arrShoes` на значение переменной `shoes` и теперь переменная `arrShoes` строка.
На следующей строчке вы переменной `shoes` присваиваете букву по из строки.

Comment: работает, спасибо, А зачем нам на второй строчке тогда setShoes? По сути он нигде не используется?

Comment: @Dolbolob Обновил ответ, добавил, как у вас работало. setShoes это у вас сейчас не используется. Хотите удалите.

Comment: спасибо за разъяснение !